# what is the difference between 'attend' and 'take part in'?

Tags: difference

I came across a question when I was writing an essay. So what is the difference between word attend and phrase take part in?

Answer (score 3):

"attend" has a more passive meaning than "take part in".

If you *attend* something, then you were present, but you didn't necessarily contribute or participate in what was going on. If you *take part in* something, then this implies that you actively participated in the event.

From Mirriam Webster:

> [attend](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attend)
>
> : to go to and be present at (an event, meeting, etc.)
>
> [take part](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20part)
>
> :  to be involved in something :  to participate in something

Comment: really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

If you were to "attend" a concert or play, then you would be part of the audience.

If you were to "take part in" the concert or play, then you would be performing in it.